# IMO 1996 problem 6

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $p, q, n$ be three positive integers with $p + q < n$. Let $(x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ be an $(n + 1)$-tuple of integers satisfying the following conditions:

(i) $x_0 = x_n = 0$;

(ii) For each $i$ with $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n$, either $x_i - x_{i - 1} = p$ or $x_i - x_{i - 1} = -q$.

Show that there exist indices $i < j$ with $(i, j) \neq (0, n)$, such that $x_i = x_j$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_i - x_{i - 1} = p$ occur $k$ times and $x_i - x_{i - 1} = -q$ occur $n - k$ times. Since $$0 = x_n - x_0 = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i - x_{i - 1}) = kp - (n - k)q,$$ we have $k (p + q) = nq$. Since $p + q < n$, we have $nq = k (p + q) < nk$, which means that $q < k$.

Since $-q > -k$, it is obvious that $kp - k (n - k) < 0$, which in turn becomes $k (p + k - n) < 0$, which means that $p + k < n$. Write it as $p + k \leqslant n - 1$, then $p + q < p + k$ implies $p + q < n - 1$.

Since the terms $x_i$ for $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n - 1$ take at most $p + q$ different values and $p + q < n - 1$, by Pigeon-hole Principle, there must be $1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant n - 1$ such that $x_i = x_j$.

"Notes on Olympiad Problems", Nima Bavari, Tehran, 2006.

Comment: If you know the answer why did you solve.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I couldn't understand your question. What do you mean?

Comment: Why do they take at most $p+q$ different values?

Comment: You have added answer so why are you asking if you already know how to solve.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I'm publishing an old notebook of mine, since math.se allows it.

Comment: @Michael Denote $d_k = x_k - x_{k - 1}$. Now, $d_k$ and $d_{k + 1}$ can take. at the extreme, $p$ and $-q$ so their difference $d_{k + 1} - d_k$ is at most $p + q$.

Comment: What is the connection between $d_{k+1}-d_k$ and $x_i-x_j=d_i+d_{i-1}+...+d_{j+1}$

Comment: I was maximizing the number of distinct $x_i$ with $d$s. @Michael